# Why Showing empty data

Tags: c#, html, sql

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=OWNER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Crmstart;Integrated Security=True");
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scon"].ConnectionString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getStudentData();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.staff (First_Name, Last_Name, Father_Name, Address, Contact_No, NIC_No, Other_Info) VALUES (@fName, @lName, @FATHERName, @AName, @CName, @NICName, @OName)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t1.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t2.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FATHERName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t3.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t4.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t5.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NICName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t6.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = t7.Value;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        getStudentData();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

When I insert data using this code my html table is showing empty rows, it is not showing any data it is just incrementing serial number I don't know what to do please help

Comment: Please first check the return value of the method ExecuteNonQuery if it is equal to one then there is no problem in your query.

Comment: Is it even inserting it into the db?

Comment: @dotNET no it is not inserting data in database.It is just auto increamenting serial no and rest of the columns remain empty.